# Angularjs creating ng-grid dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am creating ng-grid options dynamically

```
for loop
var grid = {data:'data',enableCellEdit:true//more stuff}
```

The `data:'data'` is where I am having trouble. Lets say data looks like

```
$scope.data = [];
$scope.data.push([{}]);
```

so

```
$scope.data = [];
for loop
$scope.data.push([{}]);
end loop

for loop
var grid = {data:'data[i]'//....}; // FAILING HERE
$scope.gridOptions.push(grid);
```

I can't do data[index], it will work if I explicitly say data[0] or data[1] but data[index] fails?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'data[' + index + ']', where index can be dynamic 0, or 1, etc. It will work.